# Asp.net get rid of session on server on logout after clearing cookies, session, and formsauth

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I am having trouble with a security issue of asp.net. On log out I want to make sure the session is destroyed so that someone can't take the same sessionid and auth cookies and edit there cookies and the server still responses to the session.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Clear();
```

I have also tried to write new cookies to the client

```
// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

I have tried using the following in different orders and still no dice. I can am still logged in if I use the original sessionid and Auth cookies. I want the server to totally forget about that sessionid when I logout. Is this even possible ?

Comment: Here is your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551957/3649347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server does forget about everything related to that session and so make that session id invalid when you use `Session.Clear()`.

As [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Removes all keys and values from the session-state collection

So even if someone uses the same session id there will be no information attached to it in the server.

**[Edit]**

As Erik Funkenbusch points, my solution only works if you store authentication information in the session (obviously). This won't work if you have specific cookies for your authentication system.

Comment: Yes but there has to be some kinda authorization for valid sessions  vs invalid sessions to compare to on the server otherwise anyone can just tell the server they are logged in as Joe Smith

Comment: No, because all the information which identifies you as Joe Smith is deleted with `Session.Clear()`

Comment: @Joanvo - Session has nothing to do with Authentication, which is what identifies you as Joe Smith.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the accepted answer.  You're only clearing information stored IN the session here, which cannot possibly be the determining factor for whether that session is authenticated.  That just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @MikeManard It answers the question of whether the server totally forgets about the sessionid when I logout

Comment: @Joanvo, which is why it's wrong. You're correct that this clears the session ID.The OP is saying that somebody could've copied that session ID from a previous request and use it to reauthenticate himself.  So I ask again, how is this answer even relevant?

Comment: @Joanvo, just to be clear - if the server "forgets about" the auth and session ID cookies, it will not make one bit of difference as to whether those are accepted for authentication later.

Comment: @MikeManard As I understand the question, OP says "I want the server to totally forget about that sessionid when I logout", and is asks whether any of the function calls he makes does that. My answer points out that `Session.Clear()` does it as it is described in the documentation. Furthermore, the cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId` with that value will no longer retrieve user information, which is what OP is worried about.

Comment: @Joanvo - Yet in your example someone who copied the ASP.NET_SessionId from an earlier HTTP request, or from the cookies display in Chrome, could: [1] Log out, invoking your Session.Clear(), [2] Add the cookie again through Chrome's developer tools console with one line of JavaScript, and [3] the server would respond, which is exactly what the OP does NOT want.

Comment: @Joanvo - When you say "Furthermore, the cookie ASP.NET_SessionId with that value will no longer retrieve user information," this is incorrect.  That cookie will cause the server to reinitialize that session and respond as though the request has been authenticated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way, on the server side, to clear an authentication session permanently.  You can clear the cookie, but If someone has made a copy of it, they can simply re-use it and they will get access to the site.  Auth cookies are encrypted validation tickets, which means that the site decrypts them, and validates that they decrypt correctly and are not expired.  If that's the case, then the auth cookie is valid.

Unfortunately, there's no way around this, short of using a short expiration value and updating the expiration date on a sliding window, but that means if the user is idle for a few minutes they will have to log in again.

There is no "session id" associated with an authentication ticket, although you could certainly generate a unique ID and store it in the ticket and then store that id on the server and compare it on each request to add an additional layer of security.  When you want to kill that cookie, you clear whatever ID on the server and they can no longer log in, even if the ticket is otherwise valid.

Session cookies on the other hand do have id's and are associated with internal storage mapped to that ID, so when you clear the session you also delete the storage... if you reuse that cookie then it's just going to get null data.

You can also add more security by always using encrypted cookies, and using HTTPS.  HTTPS does not store the cookies in a way that they can be acquired and re-used (they're encrypted with the SSL session, and once that SSL session is done the cookies are unusable).

Another option is to use non-persistent cookies, which don't get stored on the server.. although they can still be captured by man in the middle attacks.

To understand why there is no way around the problem, you have to understand that authentication cookies are intended to be long lived, and stored on the users computer..  When you come back, it can be a different session.  Therefore, the only way to know if the users is authenticated is to simply rely on whether the cookie can be decrypted using the servers credentials (typically machine key).  This means there is deliberately no link between a session and an authentication ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The not programmatic way to make sure all session/cookie is wiped on the server side, is to add (if not present) or change (if present) machine key in application's web.config

It can be done via IIS Manager by selecting an application, and in ASP.NET section select "Machine Key", uncheck all checkboxes and hit Generate Keys then hit Apply

Please note this is not for a single user, it will kick out all users.

[image: Machine Key - Generate]

Comment: Yes I was looking how to clean out the user from memory when they loggout of the system

Comment: I posted this answer because we wanted force everybody to re-login, and all solutions we have found on SO was about modifying cookies, and that does not work, so maybe someone will benefit from my answer, yet I didn't know where to answer exactly. The title of your Q seemed to be most neutral/relevant for my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You point on browser back button, I use bellow code (vb, but You can convert it) :

**web.config:**

```
<sessionState timeout="20" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>
```

**avsessexp.js** (auto refresh page if is inactive after 15mins) :

```
var BeatTimer;
    function StartCheck() {
        if (BeatTimer == null) {
            BeatTimer = setInterval("CheckBeat()", 900000);
        }
    }

    function CheckBeat() {
        PageMethods.PokePage();
    }
```

and call `StartCheck` function in every page (`<body onload="StarCheck();">`)

in header of every page I put :

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

**Module1.vb**

```
Public Sub CheckSession()
        With HttpContext.Current
            .Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-1))
            .Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
            .Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
            If .Session.IsNewSession = True Then LogOut()
            'there You can put some code checking is user logged, ...
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub LogOut()
        With HttpContext.Current
            .Session.RemoveAll()
            .Session.Clear()
            .Session.Abandon()
            Try
                .Response.Cookies.Add(New System.Web.HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""))
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            .Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
        End With
    End Sub
```

and, in every page (code-behind) :

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> Public Shared Sub PokePage()
        CheckSession()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       If Not IsPostBack Then CheckSession()
    End Sub
```

If You try click browser back button after logout, `CheckUser` will prevent back to prev page, and always redirect user to login page.

It's very important to use on every page/master page `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="sm1" EnablePageMethods="True"><asp:ScriptManager>`

p.s. sorry for my weak English.

Answer (score 0):

Do cookieless="true" for Session State